# How would I get the content of a http request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I'm making a discord bot and I want it to display some stats. So I got the content from a website that I want to get it from, and I used the following code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const {prefix,token} = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client()

function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

client.on('ready',() => {
    console.log('Bot ready!');
})

client.on('message',message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}http`)) {
        let result = httpGet('https://games.roblox.com/v1/games/2012508359/favorites/count')
        message.channel.send(result)
        message.reply(`Still a WIP! ${message.member.user.tag}`);
    } 
})

client.login(token);
```

It works, but it displays like this:

```
{"favoritesCount":31219}
```

How would I make it so it just displays the number (31219) and not `{"favoritesCount":31219}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing `result` you need to return the key `favoritesCount` from result in your on message handler.

You can do this by modifying you on message handler as follow:

```
client.on('message',message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}http`)) {
        let result = httpGet('https://games.roblox.com/v1/games/2012508359/favorites/count');
        const favoritesCount = JSON.parse(result).favoritesCount;
        message.channel.send(favoritesCount);
        message.reply(`Still a WIP! ${message.member.user.tag}`);
    } 
})
```

make sure you handle error response too before parsing